# Production approach react and spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, maven, production

I have started working with react.js 6 month before. Although have experience on spring boot project. Want to know best way to go for production.

1. using combined build maven copy resources plugin.

   or
2. Run both separate build one for react another for spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial to start with

[Use React and Spring Boot to Build a Simple CRUD App](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/07/19/simple-crud-react-and-spring-boot)

There is also a part about using Okta for user authentication but you can ignore it and focus on the architecture and packaging aspects.

The approach is based on packaging both React and Springboot in one WAR file and deploy a single application containing frontend and backend.
This is indeed possible using the Maven plugins (frontend-maven-plugin, maven-resources-plugin) .

Comment: Thanks for the help, but seems it more inclined towards spring security with ODIC and outh 2.0. and very little about react-spring boot production build.

Comment: There is the security aspect, true, but it is a good tutorial understand how to build and package. At least it helped me to build app which I now run on prod. Anyway good luck